# Is it safe to delete a forward_list in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, delete-operator, forward-list

I have a personal project that I'm working on it and in this personal project I used once a `forward_list` to store some informations about some files.
Then I went to play a game and suddenly I thought: is it my `f_list` destroyed safe?
In my project I just used `delete` the pointer to list.

```
std::forward_list<fileInfo> *lst;
lst = new std::forward_list<fileInfo>;
*lst = getDirectoryFiles(cfg->logDirectory);
lst->sort();
// do something
delete lst;
```

I ran a separate test (`for (uint i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) lst>push_front(i);`) and the `delete` works as expected (in task manager the memory with this list is about 77 mb and after delete is about 400 kb).

But I'm still worried if this is safe in all compilers and OSes (I tried this in MSVC2013).

Should I call first `clear()` for list, then `delete` on the pointer ?

Comment: Why would you `new` a forward_list in the first place? Yes, it is fine to delete it, but there is no need for dynamic allocation anyway.

Comment: @juanchopanza Why would someone *use* a `forward_list` in the first place? :)

Comment: @T.C. Because it is *there* :-) I guess somebody must have needed it, otherwise it wouldn't have made it into the standard. Maybe it is to stop the endless flow of "my singly linked list doesn't work" questions on SO.

Comment: I would just like to add that if you are ever unsure if you freed your memory correctly you can use valgrind for linux or Purify on windows to test for leaks.

Comment: I don t know if all the files could be stored in a continuous memory block like using a vector or array or just type [] and f_list was my first idea. And I think I need a dynamic allocation because everything except the declaration is in a loop running every few minutes. Am I wrong ?

Comment: As pointed out elsewhere, you are almost certainly better off just using automatic storage for your `forward_list` but if you must use dynamic allocation, an `std::unique_ptr<std::forward_list>` would probably be a better choice.

Comment: `forward_list` is about the most useless container in the standard library. How exactly does `vector` not suit your needs?

Comment: @T.C. the same can be said of std::list as well. Almost never preferred container.

Comment: Well, maybe I'm wrong, but I'm afraid if I use a vector I will end stacking overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine someone was walking around with a cellphone in a box.  The box had a camera inside, and a display on the outside that displayed what was on the phone in the box.  It had fancy touch waldos that would touch whatever you touched on the box, but on the phone.

It would even damage the phone if the box was damaged!

The phone screen is not displayed larger.

They come to you and ask if they can send the box (with the phone in it) to electronics recycling.

The answer is "sure, that is safe", but the real question is, why did they build the box in the first place?

The box, in this analogy, is the pointer,  The call to `new` is creating the box.  The call to `delete` is recycling it (with the phone inside).

The phone is the forward list.

Comment: Well, there might be a simple reason to build a box of such properties. For instance, it might be waterproof, while the phone is not. False analogy.

Comment: @sergeya If your pointers are waterproof the anaolgy still holds.